# Как забрать данные с запроса?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня задача забрать это сообщение и сравнить, если оно выходит, то тогда не пропускать работу, но я не понимаю как забрать этот объект отсюда, я сразу извиняюсь я не знаю, какой код нужно вставить, если у вас есть догадки или ответ как забрать message буду признателен!!

Вот фото запроса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужен код, где идет вызов этого запроса.

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Comment: @OliverPatterson [file:///C:/Users/Login/Desktop/Screenshot_1.png]